# Relationship between the Witt algebra and vector fields on the circle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have seen some (apparently contradictory) claims by mathematicians and physicists regarding the existence of an (infinite dimensional) Lie group whose Lie algebra is the Virasoro algebra.

The Virasoro algebra is a central extension of the Witt algebra, which is slightly simpler to describe and for which the same confusion is present, so I will formulate my question in that setting.

We define the Witt algebra to be $\mathfrak g:=\mathbb R[L_n\colon n\in\mathbb Z]$ where $L_n$ is the operator on the Laurent polynomial  ring $\mathbb R[z,z^{-1}]$ given by $L_np(z)=z^{1-n}p'(z)$. When equipped with the commutator of operators as Lie bracket, $\mathfrak g$ becomes an (infinite dimensional) Lie algebra.

The Witt algebra can also be described abstractly, as the Lie algebra generated by elements $(L_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ satisfying the commutation relations
$$
[L_m,L_n]=(m-n)L_{m+n},\qquad m,n\in\mathbb Z.
$$

There is also a complex Witt algebra, $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$, obtained by tensoring with $\mathbb C$. Equivalently, this is the algebra generated as above by operators acting on the Laurent polynomial ring $\mathbb C[z,z^{-1}]$.

**Question 1.** Are $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$ dense subsets of reasonable Banach algebras?

Regardless of the answer to the previous question, both $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$ can be realized as dense subsets of reasonable locally convex topological vector spaces of vector fields.

For a compact smooth manifold $M$, the group $\text{Diff}(M)$ of smooth diffeomorphisms can be given a Lie group structure such that the Lie algebra $\text{Vect}(M)$ consists of the smooth vector fields on $M$.

If I am understanding several claims by physicists correctly, taking $M=\mathbb S^1$ in the previous paragraph should yield a Lie group whose Lie algebra is closely related to either $\mathfrak g$ or $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$. This leads me to the following questions.

**Question 2.** Does $\text{Vect}(\mathbb S^1)$ contain a Lie subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak g$?

**Question 3.** What is the precise relationship between $\text{Vect}(\mathbb S^1)$ and $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$?

---

**References:**
The article [Kac-Moody and Virasoro algebras in relation to quantum physics](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0217751X86000149) by Goddard and Olive claims that the diffeomorphism group of the circle has the infinitesimal symmetries of the Witt algebra. Schottenloher's book [A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-68628-6) claims, in section 5.4, that there is no complex Virasoro group and also no complex Witt group. [Remarks on infinite dimensional Lie groups](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:16043191) by Milnor discusses infinite dimensional Lie groups modeled upon locally convex topological Lie algebras and, in particular, section 6 of that article is devoted to groups of smooth diffeomorphisms of spheres.

I have asked a related question on the [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326500/is-there-a-virasoro-group).

Comment: Re Q1: vector spaces with countably infinite Hamel bases can never be Banach (by a Baire category argument) so you might wish to rethink/rephrase - perhaps you just want a norm for which the completion has desirable properties?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I have edited Q1 to ask if those spaces are dense subsets of reasonable Banach spaces.

Comment: Let ${L_n} =  - i{e^{in\theta }}\frac{\partial }{{\partial \theta }}$. Then I think the relation becomes clear.

Comment: Care to elaborate further?

Comment: I agree with @jake that the subalgebra of Vect(M) looking like Witt is pretty standard. I believe that Diff(S^1) does admit an R-family of central extensions with Lie algebra the virasoro algebras. But I am confused about some of the analysis involved.

Comment: Please, edit the title of your question to match the questions Q1-Q3 in the body of your post. FWIW, the answers to everything are contained in Pressley and Segal's book "Loop groups".

Comment: @VictorProtsak, I have edited the title to more closely match Q1-Q3, but I have kept the mentions of the Virasoro algebra as that is the primary motivation for these questions. Jake and Theo, you have indicated how to embed the Virasoro algebra in $\text{Vect}(\mathbb S^1)\otimes \mathbb C$. But it is not clear to me how this resolves Q2 and Q3, which is why I was asking for further elaboration.

Comment: @VictorProtsak, you mention the book "Loop groups". I actually had several issues with the treatment of this topic in section 3.3 beginning on page 28. For example, in the proof of Prop 3.3.1(i) the "subgroup" $H$ is in fact not even a group if $n>1$, since the identity function is not periodic of period $2\pi/n$. Furthermore, it appears a step is missing in deducing from Prop 3.3.2 that there is no Lie group with algebra $\text{Vect}(\mathbb S^1)\otimes \mathbb C$.

Comment: As most writings of Jack Morava, "[An algebraic analog of the Virasoro group](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0109084.pdf)" is highly cryptic but extremely interesting. I think it is relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that was extremely helpful. In section 1.3, Morava fixes the first issue from "Loop groups" in the comment above, namely he clearly says what is meant by a "periodic diffeomorphism" (equivariant wrt a suitable rotation). In general the 6-page paper is extremely precise and addresses the algebraic questions, leaving the analytic ones unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

The following answers Question 2 and 3:

> For 2, $\frak{g}$ is a dense Lie subalgebra of Vect($S^1$). Tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$ gives you 3.

Identify an infinitestimal diffeomorphism on the circle to a vector field on $S^1$. Visualize a vector field as a field of tangent vectors. Each tangent vector is a multiple of $\partial_\theta$, so a vector field can be described by $A(\theta)\partial_\theta$, where $A$ is a smooth function on $S^1$. Fourier theory lets you express $A$ in terms of its Fourier series, so the space of vector fields is generated by $\{e^{in\theta}\ | n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Define

$$
L_n = -ie^{in\theta}\partial_\theta
$$

It's easy to check that these satisfy the generator relations you gave: for all smooth functions $f$ on $S^1$,

$$
[L_n,L_m]f = e^{i(n+m)\theta} i (n-m) f = (m-n) L_{n+m} f,
$$

and thus

$$
[L_n,L_m] = (m-n) L_{n+m}.
$$

Comment: Which of the question do you claim to answer? In Question 1, one wants to embed as "dense subset of a Banach algebra", which I'm struggling to make sense (Banach Lie algebra? underlying Lie algebra of an associative Banach algebra?), but at least I imagine you have some explicit Banach algebra in mind?

Comment: Ah! I came from the other post he linked to, and did not pay attention to the first question. I have edited to clarify that I'm just answering for 2 and 3.